# Cannot install node-sass using npm

Tags: node.js, npm, node-sass

I am trying to install node-sass but keep getting the same error. I have referred some answers on stackoverflow but none helped me. I can't figure out where the problem exactly lies.

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "sass_pack",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

**Command to install node-sass**

```
npm install node-sass --save-dev
```

**Error**

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\practice\sass_test>npm install node-sass --save-dev
'CALL "C:\Program Files\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" prefix -g' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

> node-sass@4.13.0 install C:\xampp\htdocs\practice\sass_test\node_modules\node-sass
> node scripts/install.js

npm WARN sass_pack@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN sass_pack@1.0.0 No repository field.

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! syscall spawn C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe;C:\xampp\php
npm ERR! file C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe;C:\xampp\php
npm ERR! path C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe;C:\xampp\php
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! node-sass@4.13.0 install: `node scripts/install.js`
npm ERR! spawn C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe;C:\xampp\php ENOENT
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the node-sass@4.13.0 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-01-04T12_02_48_301Z-debug.log
```

I don't really understand what's wrong with the command so guys please help me out

Comment: Have you tried running the terminal as admin?

Comment: Yes I already did that

Answer (score 0):

It looks like something has modified your COMSPEC to include and extra "C:\xampp\php"
You can confirm it by following the steps in the troubleshooting guide https://github.com/sass/node-sass/blob/master/TROUBLESHOOTING.md#windows

Comment: You are right. I run the command `node -p process.env.comspec` and my output is `C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe;C:\xampp\php`. According to [ https://github.com/sass/node-sass/blob/master/TROUBLESHOOTING.md#windows] my output should be `C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe`. Now how should I remove this extra `C:\xampp\php`